# Grid is not showing in Custom Module in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, module

I have made a custom module for admin in magento. Its namespace is **"Assel"** and module name is **"Character"**.

This is my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Assel_Character>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Assel_Character>
    </modules>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <character>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Assel_Character</module>
                    <frontName>character</frontName>
                </args>
            </character>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <cms>
                <children>
                    <character translate="title" module="character">
                        <title>Characters</title>
                        <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                        <action>character/adminhtml_character</action>
                    </character>
                </children>
            </cms>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <character>
                            <title>Character</title>
                        </character>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <character>
                <class>Assel_Character_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>character_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </character>
            <character_mysql4>
                <class>Assel_Character_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <character>
                        <table>character</table>
                    </character>
                </entities>
            </character_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <character_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Assel_Character</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </character_setup>
            <character_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </character_write>
            <character_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </character_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <character>
                <class>Assel_Character_Block</class>
            </character>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <character>
                <class>Assel_Character_Helper</class>
            </character>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is my Grid_Container class file named **"Character.php"** in **Assel_Character_Block_Adminhtml** folder.

```
<?php

class Assel_Character_Block_Adminhtml_Character extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_character';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'character';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('character')->__('Characters');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('character')->__('Add New Character');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

this is my Grid.php file in **Assel_Character_Block_Adminhtml_Character** folder.

```
<?php
class Assel_Character_Block_Adminhtml_Character_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('characterGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('character/character')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('character')->__('ID'),
            'align' => 'center',
            'width' => '10px',
            'index' => 'id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('character')->__('Name'),
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('alt_name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('character')->__('Alt. Name'),
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'alt_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('image', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('character')->__('Image'),
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'image',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('character')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '10',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('character')->__('Edit'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction() {

        $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('character');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
             'label'    => Mage::helper('character')->__('Delete'),
             'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
             'confirm'  => Mage::helper('character')->__('Are you sure?')
        ));



        array_unshift($statuses, array('label'=>'', 'value'=>''));
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('status', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('character')->__('Change status'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massStatus', array('_current'=>true)),
             'additional' => array(
                    'visibility' => array(
                         'name' => 'status',
                         'type' => 'select',
                         'class' => 'required-entry',
                         'label' => Mage::helper('character')->__('Status'),
                         'values' => $statuses
                     )
             )
        ));
        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
      return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }

}
```

This is the my controller file named **CharacterController.php** in **Assel_Character_controllers_Adminhtml** folder.

```
class Assel_Character_Adminhtml_CharacterController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    protected function _initAction() {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('character')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Characters Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Character Manager'));

        return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction()
            ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('character/adminhtml_character'))
            ->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

This is screenshot of my admin.
[image]

I cann't figure out what is wrong there in code so grid is not showing in backend.

Anyone Please look above code and please tell me where I am wrong..

Comment: you have any admin layout update files for your module ?

Comment: Hello @programmer_rkt, No I haven't any layout file in my admin layout folder.
Also check my updated question. I have mentiond my controller file also.

Comment: are you sure you are getting your custom collection properly? dump the collection variable `$collection = Mage::getModel('character/character')->getCollection();` and make sure it holds a collection

Comment: You are right. I am getting "bool(false)" on dump $collection variable. How can I solve it.?

Comment: See my code source http://bit.ly/dexxtz-custom-grid I made a code simple and functional

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your custom collection for grid returns nothing. ie

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('character/character')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

The protected function `_prepareCollection()` is used to set a collection for a grid which holds it. Here `$collection` is empty due to some reason and hence you are setting an empty variable via `setCollection()` method.

Why `Mage::getModel('character/character')->getCollection();` returns an empty collection. This is what you need to resolve your self. However I will give you some hints here.

Here `Mage::getModel('character/character')` expects a model class `Assel_Character_Model_Character` to be defined properly at `app/code/local/Assel/Character/Model/Character.php`. If this class is not defined correctly then it would be the problem here.

Suppose that class is defined correctly. Now you are calling a collection over your model class `Mage::getModel('character/character')->getCollection();`. Which means you need to define resource for `character` model and a `collection`. If you miss or misconfigured any one of these files, then collection would be `null`.

So what I can suggest you now is, the real problem lies in your module's `Model` directory. You have misconfigured `Character` model or its `resources`. Find it and kill it !!!! You will get output :-)

Good luck